# Convert distance matrix to adjacency matrix - Graph Analysis

Tags: r, graph, distance, adjacency-matrix

I have a dataset made up of 62 variables (categorical and numerical) and 60,000 observations. I want to generate a graph analysis from a distance matrix that I have calculated for the predictor variables.
As there is a distance between all the units evaluated, each node has the same number of vertices. I would like only those units with the shortest distance (strongest relationship). How can I do this? Is there any way to weight the distance matrix and turn it into a binary adjacency matrix?

A replicable example:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(igraph)

size=200
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(size,mean = 0, sd=1),
  x2 = rnorm(size,mean = 0, sd=1),
  x3 = rnorm(size,mean = 0, sd=1),
  x4 = sample(c(1, 0), size, replace = TRUE),
  x5 = sample(c(1, 0), size, replace = TRUE),
  x6 = sample(c(1, 0), size, replace = TRUE))
y = rnorm(size,mean = 0, sd=1)

df <- data.frame(df, row.names = paste0("ID_",1:size))

d <- dist(df, method = "euclidean")
m <- data.frame(t(combn(rownames(df),2)), as.numeric(d))
names(m) <- c("c1", "c2", "distance")

n <- cbind(paste0("ID_",1:size),sample(LETTERS[1:5],size, replace = T))
unities <- graph_from_data_frame(m, directed = FALSE, vertices = n)

set.seed(1001)
unities_deg<-degree(unities,mode=c("All"))

pal<-brewer.pal(length(unique(V(unities)$V2 )), "Set3") 
plot(unities,edge.color = 'black',vertex.label.cex =0.5, 
     vertex.color=pal[as.numeric(as.factor(vertex_attr(unities, "V2")))],
     vertex.size = sqrt(unities_deg)/3, edge.width=sqrt(E(unities)$weight/800),
     layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

Comment: right now I'm looking at making a fully-connected graph, but with connection strength being inverse to distance, and then I'm going to inject random walkers and see if I can use their mobility to make a connection graph.  Will let you know if how it goes, if I can.